# Lightning Toast Message in Tableau CRM LWC Components

Tags: lightning-web-components, toast, tableau-crm

We created a LWC to aid our users when navigating Tableau CRM Dashboards hosted in a Digital Experience Site. When users press a button, I want to show the user a toast message. However, this message is never shown.

Looking at the Documentation:

- [Platform Show Toast Event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-show-toast-event/documentation) has no mention of toast not
  working/being supported for Tableau CRM Dashboards.
- [Lightning Web Components in Tableau CRM Dashboards](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_lwc_in_db.meta/bi_dev_guide_lwc_in_db/bi_lwc_in_db_overview.htm) also makes no
  mention of toast not working/being supported.

When prefixing the toast with an alert(): the alert is shown, as is a console.log() after the toast (so the toast is fired without errors), but no toast message is shown.

What could be the reason for this?

Controller class:

```javascript
 handleButtonClick() { 
   callApexController({ // }) 
   .then( result => { 
     console.log('Button Clicked'); // shows in console 
     const evt = new ShowToastEvent({ 
       title: 'Toasty Title', 
       message: 'My message', 
       variant: 'success', 
       mode: 'sticky' }); 
     this.dispatchEvent(evt); // never happens 
     alert('Boom!'); //shows 
   }) 
  .catch( error => { 
     console.log('Something went wrong'); 
     console.error(error); // logs to console correctly 
     const evt = new ShowToastEvent({ 
       title: 'Toasty Error Title', 
       message: 'My Error Message', 
       variant: 'sticky', 
     }); 
     this.dispatchEvent(evt); // never happens 
   }); 
   alert('Boom'); // alert shows 
 }
```

From the code you can see that first I write to console, then I want to show a sticky toast that will not go away unless I click it (so I'm not to late during testing), and then I show an alert box. The first and the last actions are all executed, however the middle part that fires the toast does not.

This is observed in Tableau CRM dashboards viewed in Tableau itself, as well as TCRM Dashboards hosted in Digital experience cases (see screenshot). It looks like Toast messages are not implemented in Tableau CRM Dashboard Components, but I cannot find any mention of this in the documentation so it appears like it should work. Am I doing anything wrong?

[image: No Toast shown in Tableau Dashboard Viewer. Other alerts are shown.]

[image: No Toast shown in Digital Experience. Other alerts are shown.]

Comment: Have you tried outside of analytics studio? There's a note in this [document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_lwc_in_db.meta/bi_dev_guide_lwc_in_db/bi_lwc_in_db_get_started.htm) about lightning events only working when the dashboard is embedded in Salesforce pages (not Analytics studio).

Comment: It works when I embed the component directly in a digital experience page (not in the dashboard itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it's not mentioned in the documents you linked, it's covered in the following documentation:

- [Getting Started with LIghtning Web Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_lwc_in_db.meta/bi_dev_guide_lwc_in_db/bi_lwc_in_db_get_started.htm)
- [Perform Actions on a Salesforce Record from Tableau CRM](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bi_dashboards_actions_configure.htm&type=5)

As such, `lightning/platformShowToastEvent` is not supported specifically in Analytics Studio.

> Note
>
> If you create a **Lightning Web Component that uses Lightning events,
> the events work when your Tableau CRM dashboard is embedded in
> Salesforce pages, but not from Analytics Studio**. Analytics Studio is a
> separate Lightning app.

> Lightning components that use **Lightning events**, like
> force:createRecord or lightning:navigate, **are supported in embedded
> dashboards, but not in Analytics Studio**

Comment: So because this is embedded in a Tableau Dashboard, although it is on an Experience Site, the notification will not come through... Thanks, I'll need to talk to a few people then.